# Laravel Cartalyst/Stripe Method Not Found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments, cartalyst

I am trying to use Cartalyst/Stripe (https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe/2.0) in my Laravel application but I the method's aren't being found (for a lack of a better word).

Here is my controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Cartalyst\Stripe\Stripe;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function create_user(Request $request) {

        $stripe = Stripe::make( config('services.stripe.key') );

        $customer = $stripe->customers()->create([
            'email' => 'email@example.com',
        ]);


        return response()->json(['response' => 'This is get method']);
    }
}
```

The Stripe:make() appears to be working correctly, but the customers->() isn't found in my IDE, and produces an internal 500 error. I followed the instructions on https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe-laravel/8.x so my provider and alias are the same that are listed.

Comment: `customer` or `customers`, your code says `customers` and IDE ... just look at the actual file and see if it has those methods instead of relying on the IDE which can be wrong

Comment: customers, my apologies.

Comment: also this class has the magic method `__call` so there is no way to know what is going to be called until run time ... for missing methods, like `customers` ... your IDE wont be able to resolve a magic method call    without having been predefined to know what it will call       https://github.com/cartalyst/stripe/blob/v2.0.8/src/Stripe.php#L235

Comment: this is your `$stripe->customers()->create()` https://github.com/cartalyst/stripe/blob/v2.0.8/src/Api/Customers.php#L31

Comment: if you aren't encountering any actual errors, then it probably is working it is just your IDE not understanding the magic method call, which makes sense

Answer (score -1):

Alright so the way I have it setup does, in fact, work properly, just my IDE (phpstorm) isn't tracking the methods properly.