# Call to undefined method Cartalyst\Stripe\Api\Account::createPerson()

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I'm creating a Stripe account with Laravel by using the following syntax:

```
$making_account = $stripe->account()->create(
    [
    'type' => 'custom',
    'country' => 'au',
    'account_token' => $request[0],
    'requested_capabilities' => [
        'card_payments',
        'transfers',
      ]
    ]
);
```

The above code is working perfectly and showing the desired results. But when I create person against that account it is giving me following error:

```
local.ERROR: Call to undefined method Cartalyst\Stripe\Api\Account::createPerson()
```

Documentation that I am following is as follows:
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-tokens

After going to the Persons.php I found that there is no function named `createPerson()`. There is no way mentioned in the Stripe documentation about the Laravel syntax of creating a person against any account. Anyone knows how can I create a person in Stripe after creating an account in Laravel?

Comment: You've got a namespacing issue of some kind; Stripe isn't in the Cartalyst namespace. How are you creating `$stripe`?

Comment: I am creating in this way: `$stripe = Stripe::make(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));`

Comment: You probably need `use Stripe` at the top of the file you're doing that in.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51911396/laravel-cartalyst-stripe-method-not-found. Looks like Cartalyst has some sort of Stripe integration? If so, you probably want to follow their docs, not Stripe's; the methods may be entirely different.

Comment: I am using: use `Cartalyst\Stripe\Laravel\Facades\Stripe;`

Comment: @ceejayoz Stripe has been successfully imported, There is no issue in importing Stripe,

Comment: @ceejayoz do you have any idea about Laravel syntax on this?

Comment: deal with the documentation for the package you are using not Stripe ... this isn't Laravel's way, this is Cartalysts way, they made the package, not Laravel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to note the difference between Stripe's official PHP SDK, and any third-party libraries that might extend Stripe's packages or provide their own unique way of interacting.

Stripe has an [official PHP SDK](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php) they provide to interact with the Stripe API. **The PHP examples in Stripe's API documentation assume you are using this SDK.** If you aren't, you should check with the package you are using to see if the calls follow the same pattern, or have a different implementation.

The package you are using, [Cartalyst/Stripe](https://github.com/cartalyst/stripe), does *not* use this SDK, and as such may require a different set of calls for the same functionality.

While it doesn't appear explicitly documented, I *think* the equivalent API in the Cartalyst package might be:

```php
$stripe->account()->persons()->create(/* ... */);
```